# This MySQLI query will not work/ Is there an issue with my web server SQL settings?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

This is the code I have for the query:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 1";
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user , $pass , $database);
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or 
die("Couldn't execute query.");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row;
```

Does anyone see any obvious problems with this that would stop it from executing? $host, $user etc are defined in a separate config file.

This is the error message I get:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in
/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/bu/ck/et/public_html/admin/config.php on line 8
Connect failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have read that this means there is an issue with an SQL setting, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: yes there is, look into webserver admin panel what is database server (usually 'localhost' but sometimes not) check your db name (sometimes they add a prefix)

Comment: MySQL is not running or something is misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks guys. So is the code ok? Im new to mysqli so would like to be sure that what im spending my time writing is logical and will work with a working SQL setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql did not use default location for the socket, which is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

So, check your configuration to find out the actual socket file, and replace the connection string accordingly, see [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)